# jquery: turn updating number into progress bar?

Tags: jquery

so i have this div

```
<div id="progress">{2 digit number updates here}</div>
```

What's the best way to turn this into a progress bar?

something like this?

```
<div id="progress">
     <div id="bar" style="width={2 digit number updates here}"></div>
</div>
```

would this be 'ok'?!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very nearly. You'd want to express your update as a percentage, so that you can show something like:

```
<div id="progress" width="400px;"><!-- maximum width of your bar -->
    <div id="bar" style="width: {percentage complete goes here}%;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you beat me to the answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to VoteyDisciples answer you could also use the [jQuery UI Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) and updating the percentage with `.progressbar( "value" , 25 )`